# what are some good libraries for parallel programming with builtin constructs

Tags: multithreading, clojure, parallel-processing

I'm learning parallel programming with book [The Art of Parallel Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1595408398). This book uses `C*` language built on top of C.

C* has its own constructs like `forall` which is supercool. It creates as many parallel processes as I want. Processes here mean the parallel tasks to be executed simultaneously.

eg.

```
struct Artist {
             char name[12];
             char desc[6][20];
             int plays;
          };

struct Artist artists[10000];

forall index = 1 to sizeof(artists) grouping 1000 do

    sendEmail(artists[index])
```

This will create a process of 1000 records each, if there are 10000 records then will create 10000/1000 = 10 processes. Each process will send email to Artist in parallel.

I was curious if there are languages out there with similar constructs which can be used in production.

C* seems a nice compiler for academic purpose, but no way good for production, also its not open source and only runs on `Window OS`.

[I looked upon golang, but I dont think it has one.](http://www.golangpatterns.info/concurrency/parallel-for-loop).

[I read that Fortress has parallel for loop.](https://java.net/downloads/projectfortress/reference.pdf)

eg. fortress

```
for l <- seq(f.lines) do println l end
for l ← seq(f .lines) do println l end
```

clojure, golang, rust whatever compiler/ libraries are welcome for such parallel programming.

Answer (score 1):

you might also want to take a look at [reducers](http://clojure.org/reference/reducers), which a nice builtin mechanism for some parallel computations:

```
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])

(defn par-map [chunk-size f coll]
  (r/fold chunk-size
          (fn ([] []) ([c1 c2] (concat c1 c2)))
          conj
          (r/map f coll)))

(par-map 10 inc (vec (range 100)))
```

but you should remember, that the collection should be foldable (e.g. persistent vector or map)

Comment: this is the better answer among those experienced with multithreading in clojure. the built-in pmap is inferior to reducers or other alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Clojure certainly has all the constructs to do what you're looking for.  `pmap`, for instance, will lazily apply a function to a sequence of elements in parallel.  It doesn't group elements by itself, but it can easily be combined with the `partition-all` function to partition the original sequence into groupings of a specified size.  `concat` can then be used to join the results back into a single sequence.

For example, here's a function that will map a function over two sequences in parallel, with a specified group size:

```
(defn pmap-grouping [f group-size xs ys]
    (apply concat (pmap (partial mapv f)
                        (partition-all group-size xs)
                        (partition-all group-size ys))))
```

For example, `(pmap-grouping + 2 [1 2 3] [4 5 6])` returns `(5 7 9)`.  Note that I've written `pmap-grouping` to take a fixed number of sequences to reduce unfamiliar syntax, but it's just as trivial to re-write it to work with an arbitrary number of sequences (any number 1 or greater):

```
(defn pmap-grouping [f group-size & cols]
    (apply concat (apply pmap (partial mapv f)
                              (map (partial partition-all group-size)
                                   cols))))
```

Note that there are a few differences between this implementation using `pmap` and your description of `forall`.  For example, `pmap` uses (up to) a fixed number of threads.  On the other hand, this is probably what you want, since too many threads will lead to thrashing.

Even if Clojure didn't have `pmap`, it would be possible to write your own `pmap` working directly with threads.  It would definitely be more work, but certainly possible.  In fact, all you really need is a language that supports threads and higher-order functions.  Furthermore, functions are isomorphic to objects (i.e., you can implement functions with objects, and vice versa).  So virtually any language that supports threads will work.

So far, we've discussed a functional approach.  If you use a functional language, this approach is pretty clean and composes well.  However, if you want to get syntactic abstraction as well, Clojure macros are excellent for this.

In summary:

- You can do parallel programming in any language with threads, although you might need to do more work in some languages than others.
- Functional languages allow parallel computations to be expressed succinctly and in a composable manner.
- If you want syntactic abstraction, you will either have to use a language with the desired syntax builtin, or use a language (such as Clojure) that supports syntax extensions via, e.g., macros.

Comment: see section on this page about `pmap`: https://rasterize.io/blog/clojure-the-good-parts.html

Comment: @johnbakers  Choice of `pmap` was arbitrary in order to answer a very general question.  It's not meant to indicate in any way it is the best way to do parallel computation in Clojure.  The point is, functions in the spirit of `pmap` are basically `forall`, except for the syntactic sugar and a few implementation details (e.g., laziness, partitioning, etc.) that might or might not be important.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out: http://www.clojure-toolbox.com

It is a great resource.